# Can someone confirm that the sender will receive the correct amount of tokens?

Tags: solidity, tokens, ico

I've tried to get this to work. But every time I deposit 1 Finney it only gives me 0.00000000000000000001 Tokens.

What am I missing?

For every 1 Finney, I want the buyer to receive 1 KEFT token automatically.

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract KidsEducationFund {

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;

    address owner = 0x0121B8054c407533E7A56fC85c148CDfCF094BAc;

    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    function KidsEducationToken() public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = 1000;
        name = "Kids Education Fund Token";
        symbol = "KEFT";
    }

    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require(_to != 0x0);
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    function () payable public {
        require(msg.value >= 0);
        uint tokens = msg.value / 1 finney;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += tokens;
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your contract is allocating 1 KEFT token per Finney sent.

However, the `decimals` parameter affects how people will see this when they look up the token in their wallet UIs.  ERC20 tokens like this have a `decimals` parameter that specifies the number of decimal places for display purposes, because for some reason people like to think of tokens having fractional parts even when they don't.  Since you have `decimals` set to 18, the single KEFT token in the contract is displayed as 0.000000000000000001 tokens in the UI.

To "fix" this you need to either:

- set your decimals to 0 (no decimal places), so one contract token is displayed as 1 KEFT token, or
- do `uint tokens = 10 ** decimals * msg.value / 1 finney;`, so that 1 Finney = 10^18 contract tokens which is displayed as 1.000000000000000000 KEFT.  You can reduce `decimals` here if you want fewer DPs; 18 is a bit overkill.

Comment: Thanks. So If I set decimals to 1, then 1 finney would buy 1 KEFT token?

Comment: Yep.  In that case you won't be able to issue or transfer fractions of a token. If you want to be able to use fractions of a token, you need to do the second thing, and set `decimals` to however many decimal places you want UAs to display. IMHO `decimals = 1` is the simplest and most intuitive approach (whole tokens only).

Comment: I've edited with more explanation and corrected: `decimals = 0` is what you need. Apologies.

Comment: Hi @SamWolf - Did this answer your question? If so it would be good to mark it as answered for the benefit of others.